# asking for offline_access ignored

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I have a problem to define the required permission an user should allow to my application.
Actually, just the offline_access doesn't work.

I put it in the app description (Authenticated Referrals) and when the user asks for authorization

> $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
>       client_id=".$app_id
>       ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)
>       ."&scope=**offline_access**"                                      >
>   ."&state=".$_SESSION['state'];

I can't understand why, when the oauth dialog appears, no offline permission is asked! i've already tried to remove and reinstall the application.

Any suggestion?  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has been deprecated, see this page for an explanation on what to do now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), `offline_access` will be prompted on a second page during the OAuth dialog. Are you clicking through the first page, and simply not seeing a second page?

Comment: tried with email and publish_stream and works. Nothing for offline_access.       What is the difference between scopes in the app details, and scopes required in the OAuth dialog? they seems independent.

Answer (score 0):

Unedestood because it was ignored.  I had the

> deprecate offline_access = true

why they deprecated it? Is there a new way to do it?